# Rows of divs not lining up correctly

Tags: css

Question regarding styling. I have a row of `div` elements. They're all the same size except one, which is double in height and width. I'd like the second row of `div` elements to line up with the second half of the bigger `div` but now sure how to do it.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box-5 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box box-1">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box box-2">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box box-3">Box 3</div>
  <div class="box box-4">Box 4</div>
  <div class="box box-5">Box 5</div>
  <div class="box box-6">Box 6</div>
  <div class="box box-7">Box 7</div>
  <div class="box box-8">Box 8</div>
  <div class="box box-9">Box 9</div>
  <div class="box box-10">Box 10</div>
  <div class="box box-11">Box 11</div>
  <div class="box box-12">Box 12</div>
  <div class="box box-13">Box 13</div>
  <div class="box box-14">Box 14</div>
  <div class="box box-15">Box 15</div>
  <div class="box box-16">Box 16</div>
  <div class="box box-17">Box 17</div>
  <div class="box box-18">Box 18</div>
  <div class="box box-19">Box 19</div>
</div>
```

[image: screenshot-divs]

I'd like box 13 - 16 to be on the left side of the bottom half of box 5 and box 17 - 19 to be on the right side.

Comment: What you're looking for is a masonry layout. That is somewhat achievable using CSS grid or flexbox, but requires you to know the layout you want beforehand. If the larger box 5 is actually dynamic (i.e. it can happen to any other boxes, too), then you will need a JS-based layout solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use CSS `display: grid` and its companion `grid-template-columns` to fix this. Updated answer thanks to Maaz Syed Adeeb's comment.

```css
grid-template-columns: repeat(13, auto);
```

*(It should be **thirteen** instead of 12 boxes).*

Only box number 5 gets an upgrade in styling to expand its box:

```css
grid-column: span 2;
grid-row: span 2;
```

Read more about grid at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid).

Updated snippet:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(13, auto);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 0;
}

.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box-5 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box box-1">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box box-2">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box box-3">Box 3</div>
  <div class="box box-4">Box 4</div>
  <div class="box box-5">Box 5</div>
  <div class="box box-6">Box 6</div>
  <div class="box box-7">Box 7</div>
  <div class="box box-8">Box 8</div>
  <div class="box box-9">Box 9</div>
  <div class="box box-10">Box 10</div>
  <div class="box box-11">Box 11</div>
  <div class="box box-12">Box 12</div>
  <div class="box box-13">Box 13</div>
  <div class="box box-14">Box 14</div>
  <div class="box box-15">Box 15</div>
  <div class="box box-16">Box 16</div>
  <div class="box box-17">Box 17</div>
  <div class="box box-18">Box 18</div>
  <div class="box box-19">Box 19</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could use `grid-template-columns: repeat(12, auto)` instead. Excellent solution!

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb Why didn't I think of it! Adjusted the answer and gave you credit where due. Thanks!

Answer (score -7):

Just need to add 10 more pixel in `width`

```
.box-5 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 110px;
}
```

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 800px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.box{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  
}

.box-5 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 110px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box box-1">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box box-2">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box box-3">Box 3</div>
    <div class="box box-4">Box 4</div>
  <div class="box box-5">Box 5</div>
  <div class="box box-6">Box 6</div>
    <div class="box box-7">Box 7</div>
  <div class="box box-8">Box 8</div>
  <div class="box box-9">Box 9</div>
    <div class="box box-10">Box 10</div>
    <div class="box box-11">Box 11</div>
  <div class="box box-12">Box 12</div>
  <div class="box box-13">Box 13</div>
    <div class="box box-14">Box 14</div>
  <div class="box box-15">Box 15</div>
  <div class="box box-16">Box 16</div>
    <div class="box box-17">Box 17</div>
  <div class="box box-18">Box 18</div>
  <div class="box box-19">Box 19</div>
</div>
```